# Haproxy "use_backend" match order

Tags: rewrite, haproxy

I have a problem with HAProxy, it's a snippet of my **haproxy.cfg** below,

```
acl url_a path_beg   /a
acl dom_eye hdr_dom(host) -i www.mydomin.com
use_backend eye1 if dom_eye
use_backend eye2 if dom_eye url_a
```

1. when i visit *www.mydomin.com/a*, it  use **eye2**
2. when i visit *www.mydomin.com/a/b*, it use **eye1**

but I would expect that all the url begin with **/a** use eye2.

And, I found that when switch the order of **use_backend** like below,

```
acl url_a path_beg   /a
acl dom_eye hdr_dom(host) -i www.mydomin.com
use_backend eye2 if dom_eye url_a
use_backend eye1 if dom_eye
```

it worked for me.

But I don't understand the "match order rule" of Haproxy and can't find any explain from google.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but the HAProxy documentation states:

> There may be as many "use_backend" rules as desired. All of these rules are
>   evaluated in their declaration order, and the first one which matches will
>   assign the backend.

From: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4-use_backend

Looking at your code:

```
acl url_a path_beg /a
acl dom_eye hdr_dom(host) -i www.mydomin.com
use_backend eye1 if dom_eye
use_backend eye2 if dom_eye url_a
```

I would expect the following results:

```
www.mydomin.com -> eye1
www.mydomin.com/a -> eye1
www.mydomin.com/a/b -> eye1
```

Because all of them match the first `use_backend`.

If you change the config to:

```
acl url_a path_beg /a
acl dom_eye hdr_dom(host) -i www.mydomin.com
use_backend eye2 if dom_eye url_a
use_backend eye1 if dom_eye
```

I would expect these results:

```
www.mydomin.com -> eye1
www.mydomin.com/a -> eye2
www.mydomin.com/a/b -> eye2
```

Because only URL 2 and 3 match the first `use_backend`.

Could you confirm this is not what happens in your config?

Comment: I read it before ask here ,that is why I'm so confusedly now.

Comment: Please see my edits.

Comment: under the first case of configuration,
www.mydomin.com/a will be redirect to eye2.

Comment: Inconceivable, but it's very well in production environment.thanks.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept and/or upvote my answer :)

Comment: Of course, helped me, i like to upvote your answer if i reach 15 reputation,so ,so sorry :(